# Wordpress (Woocommerce) order by Product Dimensions (Length, Width, and then Height)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to order my products by Length and Width, where it sorts by length first and, if two products have the same value, it will sort by Width (and so on). I would like to add height if I can get this working first.

So far the issue I'm running into is that it orders the products by length and only length (plus a bug where even the length is incorrect, i.e. the product order is 2.1, 2, and 2.5).

This is as far as I've gotten with the query:

```
function woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'length_clause' => array(
            'key'     => '_length',
            'type' => 'DECIMAL',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        ),
        'width_clause' => array(
            'key'     => '_width',
            'type' => 'DECIMAL',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        ),
    );

    $args['orderby'] = array(
        'length_clause' => 'ASC',
        'width_clause' => 'ASC',
    );

    return $args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
```

I'm convinced I'm missing something obvious that I just can't see at the moment. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Another dead end for this search. Why is ordering by two different meta keys so difficult?

Comment: @freethebees From everything I've read since then it isn't possible using Wordpress' filter. I haven't started down this path yet (I've been putting it off, tbh), but I think the next step is to just go with a modified SQL query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database. :/

Answer (score 0):

In your case you must add priority when you add a filter for woocommerce.
Here is the working code for sorting by meta values:

/**

- Save product attributes to post metadata when a product is saved.
- 
- @param int $post_id The post ID.
- @param post $post The post object.
- @param bool $update Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
- Source: https://www.webhat.in/article/woocommerce-tutorial/custom-order-by-attributes/
- Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post/
  */

```html
'''
 function wh_save_product_custom_meta($post_id, $post, $update) {
        $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
        // If this isn't a 'product' post, don't update it.
        if ($post_type != 'product')
            return;
    
        if (!empty($_POST['attribute_names']) && !empty($_POST['attribute_values'])) {
            $attribute_names = $_POST['attribute_names'];
            $attribute_values = $_POST['attribute_values'];
            foreach ($attribute_names as $key => $attribute_name) {
                switch ($attribute_name) {
                    //for color (string)
                    case 'pa_color':
                        //it may have multiple color (eg. black, brown, maroon, white) but we'll take only the first color.
                        if (!empty($attribute_values[$key][0])) {
                            update_post_meta($post_id, 'pa_color', $attribute_values[$key][0]);
                        }
                        break;
                    //for lenght (int)
                    case 'pa_length':
                        if (!empty($attribute_values[$key][0])) {
                            update_post_meta($post_id, 'pa_length', $attribute_values[$key][0]);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    add_action( 'save_post', 'wh_save_product_custom_meta', 10, 3);
'''
```

Answer (score -1):

Custom sorting can be added using: please follow the step according and replace your meta value

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/custom-sorting-options-ascdesc/